# AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I got this error when using a package to read hdf5 files:

```
dataset.value
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 163, in <module>
    train(0, False, args.gpu_list, args.model_path)
  File "train.py", line 76, in train
    dataset = Ani1Dataset(dir_path='/data/ANI-1_release')
  File "/code/ani1dataset.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.parse(dir_path)
  File "/code/ani1dataset.py", line 32, in parse
    for molecule in adl:
  File "/code/pyanitools.py", line 75, in __iter__
    for data in self.h5py_dataset_iterator(self.store):
  File "/code/pyanitools.py", line 71, in h5py_dataset_iterator
    yield from self.h5py_dataset_iterator(item, path)
  File "/code/pyanitools.py", line 60, in h5py_dataset_iterator
    dataset = np.array(item[k].value)
AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: In the code above, if `item[k]` references a HDF5 dataset, you can read it into a NumPy array using `dataset = item[k][:]`. Much cleaner. Also, I would not downgrade to h5py 2.9.0 without a compelling reason. It was released 2014. The current h5py release is 3.2 and supports newer HDF5 formats and has many enhancements and error corrections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `.value` has been deprecated for some time. As mentioned in my comments above,  I would not downgrade to h5py 2.9.0 without a compelling reason. It was released in 2014. The current h5py release is 3.2 and supports the latest HDF5 formats and has many enhancements and error corrections.

There are 2 primary ways to access HDF5 data with h5py. Briefly, you can:

1. Return a h5py dataset object. A dataset object behaves "as-if" it is an array, but does not load the data into memory until needed.
2. Return a NumPy array. This immediately loads the data into memory.

[Complete h5py dataset documentation here:](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data)
Examples of each below:

```
with h5py.File('filename.h5','r') as h5f:
    # return a h5py dataset object:
    my_ds_obj = h5f[ds_name]
    # return a h5py dataset object:
    my_ds_arr = h5f[ds_name][()]
```

In addition, if you only want to read some of the data, h5py supports most NumPy slicing syntax, including a subset of fancy indexing. [h5py fancy indexing doc](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html#dataset-fancy)

Answer (score 11):

The dataset.value attribute was deprecated. Either use:

```
dataset[()]
```

or downgrade `h5py` to use the old syntax:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install h5py=='2.9.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

.value is deprecated.Use h5f['kVals'][()] rather than h5f['kVals'].value

[Copied the above code from this link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/dont-understand-what-h5py-people-are-thinking/26387)