# Problems with h5py - 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, h5py

I'm currently trying to read in data from a h5py file and running into problems when attempting to slice and the metadata within to then input into a dictionary. The code is taken straight from [NSF Neon tutorials](https://www.neonscience.org/resources/learning-hub/tutorials/neon-hsi-aop-functions-tiles-py) where the entire script can be found.

I'm particularly having trouble with this area of the function;

```
  #Extract the reflectance & wavelength datasets
    refl = hdf5_file[sitename]['Reflectance']
    reflData = refl['Reflectance_Data']
    reflRaw = refl['Reflectance_Data'].value ##This is causing - Dataset' object has no attribute 'value'
    
   #Create dictionary containing relevant metadata information
    metadata = {}
    metadata['map info'] = refl['Metadata']['Coordinate_System']['Map_Info'].value ##As above
    metadata['wavelength'] = refl['Metadata']['Spectral_Data']['Wavelength'].value
```

From looking at [this previous question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409919/attributeerror-dataset-object-has-no-attribute-value) it seems that `.value` has be deprecated with recent releases with h5py.
Referencing that post, instead of;

`reflRaw = refl['Reflectance_Data'].value`

I've tried

- `reflRaw = refl['Reflectance_Data'][:]`

  *For this Python accuses me of 'Illegal slicing argument for scalar
  dataspace'*
- `reflRaw = refl['Reflectance_Data'][()]`

  *This just hangs for 30 seconds and then eventually shows a blank
  matplotlib plot*

Not sure how to proceed here. These tutorials are relatively recent so I'm not sure how they managed to get `.value` working if it's been deprecated in al recent h5py releases.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer you linked shows, the correct syntax for newer versions of h5py is to replace `.value` with `[()]`. Doing this worked for me in your example. I'm not sure what you mean when you say the function returns a blank matplotlib plot, since it's only meant to return 2 arrays - which, again, it does when I run it.